# Why is graph convolution network in time-varying graphs useful for anomaly detection?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, applications, geometric-deep-learning

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08097), the authors refer to the application of time-varying graphs as an open problem.　And they say it will be useful for anomaly detection in financial networks, etc. But why is that useful?